# Searching in Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, contains

Having a dataframe with ngrams of Italian text. Looking like that:

```
    Name
0   accensione del drive ribobinatrice ho
1   actions urgente proporre al cliente
2   al cliente upgrade del drive
3   al drive con una smontata
4   causa di un problema di
```

I would like to search for combination of words `'cliente problema'`

In my logics it should give me row number 1,2 and 4.

Using the approach with `contains()` but it returns the empty Series:

```
Term = 'cliente problema'

x_word = df_pentagrams.Name[df_pentagrams.Name.str.contains(Term)]
```

How can this problem be solved in Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the '|' character to join your separate terms in the search string. At the moment your code attempts to match the entire 'cliente problema' string, which none of your rows contain.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['accensione del drive ribobinatrice ho',
'actions urgente proporre al cliente',
'al cliente upgrade del drive',
'al drive con una smontata',
'causa di un problema di',], columns = ['Name'])

Term = 'cliente problema'

x_word = df.Name[df.Name.str.contains('|'.join(Term.split(' ')))]
```

Comment: This method may not suit because it doesn't filter for words in `Name`, e.g. `problematic` would be caught.

Answer (score 2):

Your expectations are wrong regarding the behavior of `str.contains`.  As you are using `str.contains` in your example you are searching for an explicit string `cliente problema`, but based on your expectation you aren't looking for `clienta problema` as a string, but for either `clienta` or `problema` occurring in any of the records.

Instead of treating `clienta problema` as a string you should split that string into a list and then use that list when you filter the `DataFrame`:

```
terms = term.split(' ')
df_penagrams.Name[df_pentagrams.Name.str.contains('|'.join(terms))
```

Comment: This method may not suit because it doesn't filter for words in `Name`, e.g. `problematic` would be caught.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are searching for the *exact* string 'cliente problema' not 'cliente' OR 'problema'.

This is what you want to do:

```
    Term1 = 'cliente' 
    Term2 = 'problema'

    x_word = df_pentagrams.Name[df_pentagrams.Name.str.contains(Term1) 
| df_pentagrams.Name.str.contains(Term2)]
```

Comment: My answer was posted before I saw vealkind's. I prefer their solution as it scales to any number of search terms.

Comment: This method may not suit because it doesn't filter for words in `Name`, e.g. `problematic` would be caught.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either regex or a list comprehension to filter for words:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['accensione del drive ribobinatrice ho',
                            'actions urgente proporre al cliente',
                            'al cliente upgrade del drive',
                            'al drive con una smontata',
                            'causa di un problema di']})

Term = 'cliente problema'

# regex
p = '|'.join(Term.split())
res = df[df['Name'].str.contains(r'\b{}\b'.format(p))]

# list comprehension
res = df[[any(i in words for i in Term.split()) \
          for words in df['Name'].str.split().values]]

print(res)

                                  Name
1  actions urgente proporre al cliente
2         al cliente upgrade del drive
4              causa di un problema di
```